# parsing some text without the numbering

Tags: php

I have text file that contain for example :

```
1. I code
2. I eat
```

I wanna parsing only the sentence into some string and count every word in string and ignore the number. But in the result I wanna write again the number. SO The result i wanna get is :

```
1. I(1) code(4)
2. I(1) eat(3)
```

I thought. first i have to replace the number with ''

```
function checkFirstWord2($string) {
   $arr = explode(' ',trim($string));
   $arrpke= str_replace($arr[0],'', $arr);
   return $arrpke;
}
```

main program :

```
$file  = "C:/AppServ/www/kbbi/cobaangka.txt";
$lines = file($file);
foreach($lines as $line_num => $line) {
   $first = checkFirstWord2($line);
   $count = count(explode('',$first);
   echo $first.'('.$count.')'; // but how to write again the number 1. and 2. ?
}
```

I don;t know ho to write again the number of sentence : `1.` and `2.` ?
please help me, thank you :)

Comment: What are `3` and `4`? Word lengths?

Comment: @thg435 it is the number of letter in every words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea, but some of your functions were wrong.

1. First split the line into parts
2. Store the line number for later
3. Go through each of the remaining words and print out the length of the word

-

```
$file  = "file.txt";
$lines = file($file);
foreach($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    $line_parts = explode(' ', $line); //split the line into parts
    $line_number    = array_shift($line_parts);//take out the first part of the line, the number

    echo $line_number . ' ';//add space so it doesn't get stcuck to other letters

    //loop through each of the line parts, and count the number of letters
    foreach ($line_parts as $part) {
        if (empty($part)) continue; //ignore spaces if any

        $part           = trim($part);//some cleanup for trailing spaces
        $lettercount    = strlen($part);
        echo "$part($lettercount) "; //print the output word by word
    }    
    echo "<br>";
 }
```

This will output

```
1. I(1) code(4)
2. I(1) eat(3)
```

Note - You don't need to store the line number separately if you know they will always be in sequence. If they are always in sequence you can use the index available in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
$file  = "C:/AppServ/www/kbbi/cobaangka.txt";
$lines = file($file);
foreach($lines as $line) {
   $tmp   = explode('. ', $line);
   $new_line = $tmp[0] . ". ";
   foreach(explode(' ', $tmp[1]) as $word)
   {
       $new_line .= $word . "(" . strlen($word) . ") ";
   }

   echo $new_line;
}
```

tested

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, provided each of the sentences are on a new line.

```
$lines = explode("\n", $string);
$der = preg_replace('/\d\. /', '', $lines);
```

And now `print_r($der);` returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => I code
    [1] => I eat
)
```

---

**Explanation**

First we explode the sentences on their new lines:

```
explode("\n", $string);
```

That gives us an array that looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1. I code
    [1] => 2. I eat
)
```

And now you want to remove the line numbers (*I pressume thats what they are?*) from the sentences. For that we need to use a regex : `/\d\. /`

```
preg_replace('/\d\. /', '', $lines);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

- First, of course, get the file
- Then secondly, loop the data, under the loop, explode each line, then iterate on that exploded line and get the length of each word.
- Of course, lastly, put them back together.

Sample values:

```
1. I code
2. I eat
3. I sleep
4. You jump
5. They curse all
6. I saw
```

Consider this example:

```
$final = '';
$file  = "cobaangka.txt";
$lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    $pieces = array_filter(explode(' ', $line)); // explode them
    $line_num = array_shift($pieces); // get the line number

    // each words, calculate the number of characters
    $complete = array_map(function($var){
        return $var.'('.strlen($var).') ';
    }, $pieces);

    // and finally, put them back together
    $final .= $line_num .' '.implode($complete) . "\n";
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($final);
```

`$final` should yield something like:

```
1. I(1) code(4) 
2. I(1) eat(3) 
3. I(1) sleep(5) 
4. You(3) jump(4) 
5. They(4) curse(5) all(3) 
6. I(1) saw(3)
```